# Rails: How do I keep a complex app RESTful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I always try to make my applications as RESTful as possible but I've recently begun working on a complex project that requires multiple additional methods in my controller.

I normally achieve this by adding another :collection to the route but it seems like a workaround and in on scenario I have 5.

Are there any best practices for handling the extra methods in a controller? They are generally simple forms that updates a model.

Comment: Could you add some specifics? What is the controller/resource and what are the extra methods you are adding? I usually find there is a good way to handle it RESTfully it just takes getting some outside perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other solution, which is what I do, is every time you find yourself creating an action that doesn't fit into the RESTful actions, eg Search, so you might find yourself making a search action on an Article controller, what you could do instead of creating this action is create a Search controller instead, and use RESTful actions inside of that instead. There is no rule saying you need to use all the actions, you might only need one or two, but it keeps your API RESTful and your code organised.

This is not a hard and fast rule, but I have certainly found it helpful when I try to decide where to put stuff.

Comment: As a great example of this (even involving search!) check out the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a bit of confusion in the Rails community about how and where to use the word "RESTful". Strictly speaking, the only thing that can be RESTful is your **web API** (as railsninja already mentioned). That the code of an application that conforms to the REST conventions (the application with REST API) can usually be organized into a set of controllers (that match the resources) and methods in these controllers (that match the four verbs of the HTTP protocol) is nothing but a hint of how to keep your application clean and organized.

If we want to talk about a RESTful Rails application, we can't just talk about RESTful controllers - there's nothing RESTful about just controllers themselves. It's possible to have a complex web application with only one controller (and myriad of methods) that represents many resources and is perfectly RESTful.

That said, it's pretty OK to add more methods to your controller. Sometimes, it's good to extract some of these extra methods and create a completely new controller - make this any time you feel good about it (rule of a thumb: create new controller anytime you are able to identify it with some self-sufficient resource, ie. a resource which could exist just by itself). Sometimes though, it'd be silly to extract some resource to a different controller. Say you have a resource which has a status attribute. It makes sense to perceive this status attribute as a resource by itself and perform at least one action on it (update), but it won't make any good to extract it to a different controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Railscast about this topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/35-custom-rest-actions), adding custom actions to an otherwise RESTful controller.

Edit: I see that you've mentioned the method in the Railscast as a workaround already. :-) I believe the only other "pure" way to handle it would be to add additional controllers as required to support the actions you want.

Answer (score 1):

"I normally achieve this by adding another :collection to the route but it seems like a workaround and in on scenario I have 5. "

This sounds perfectly fine to me. REST is not about the crud operations and your concern seems to stem from the fact that you are doing more than the basic crud operations but there's nothing wrong with that.